# How to call a method of a module properly in ruby C-api?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension, c-api, ruby-module

I am trying to write a fuzzing harness for [this open source regex library](https://github.com/Shopify/onigmo/tree/main) , but I am running into a problem that I do not know how to call a module in the ruby C-api properly.

My current harness code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize ruby
    ruby_init();

    // Define example regex string
    VALUE x;
    x = rb_str_new_cstr("a"); // Very simple regex which maches an "a" character

    
    // Initialize the Onigmo module
    printf("Initializing the Onigmo module...\n");

    VALUE rb_cOnigmo = rb_define_module("Onigmo");

    rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cOnigmo, "parse", parse, 1);
    rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cOnigmo, "compile", compile, 1);

    rb_cOnigmoNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "Node", rb_cObject);
    rb_cOnigmoAlternationNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AlternationNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorBufferBeginNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorBufferBeginNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorBufferEndNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorBufferEndNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorKeepNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorKeepNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorLineBeginNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorLineBeginNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorLineEndNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorLineEndNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorPositionBeginNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorPositionBeginNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorSemiEndNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorSemiEndNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorWordBoundaryNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorWordBoundaryNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnchorWordBoundaryInvertNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnchorWordBoundaryInvertNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoAnyNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "AnyNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoBackrefNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "BackrefNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoCallNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "CallNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoCClassNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "CClassNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoCClassInvertNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "CClassInvertNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoEncloseAbsentNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "EncloseAbsentNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoEncloseConditionNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "EncloseConditionNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoEncloseMemoryNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "EncloseMemoryNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoEncloseOptionsNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "EncloseOptionsNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoEncloseStopBacktrackNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "EncloseStopBacktrackNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoListNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "ListNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoLookAheadNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "LookAheadNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoLookAheadInvertNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "LookAheadInvertNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoLookBehindNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "LookBehindNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoLookBehindInvertNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "LookBehindInvertNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoQuantifierNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "QuantifierNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoStringNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "StringNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoWordNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "WordNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);
    rb_cOnigmoWordInvertNode = rb_define_class_under(rb_cOnigmo, "WordInvertNode", rb_cOnigmoNode);



    printf("Creating instance of rb_cOnigmo...\n");
    VALUE module_object = rb_class_new_instance(0, NULL, rb_cOnigmo);
    printf("Trying to call \"parse\" on the module...\n");
    rb_funcall(module_object, rb_intern("parse"), 1, x);
    printf("Done!\n");

    // Cleanup
    return ruby_cleanup(0);
}
```

after compiling and trying to run, I get this output:

```
Initializing the Onigmo module...
Creating instance of rb_cOnigmo...
ruby: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000040
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:0008c0 (none) [FINISH]


-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007fc7cd3d2ca9 RBP: 0x00005614b0a0b850 RSP: 0x00007ffca19ce140
 RAX: 0x0000000000000000 RBX: 0x00005614b0a64d28 RCX: 0x0000000000000003
 RDX: 0x0000000000000010 RDI: 0x00005614b0a0b850 RSI: 0x0000000000000006
  R8: 0x0000000000000000  R9: 0x00005614b0b32ab0 R10: 0x00005614b0b32900
 R11: 0x00007fc7cd239ce0 R12: 0x0000000000000006 R13: 0x00007fc7cd69c560
 R14: 0x0000000000000008 R15: 0x00005614b00db7a8 EFL: 0x0000000000010206

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0x7fc7cd57a0d0) [0x7fc7cd57a0d0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0x7fc7cd3ce4f4) [0x7fc7cd3ce4f4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0x7fc7cd4ee4ed) [0x7fc7cd4ee4ed]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__restore_rt+0x0) [0x7fc7cd061520]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0x7fc7cd3d2ca9) [0x7fc7cd3d2ca9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0x7fc7cd3d8502) [0x7fc7cd3d8502]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0xa9662) [0x7fc7cd3d8662]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0x7fc7cd3cea0b) [0x7fc7cd3cea0b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(rb_check_type+0x3c) [0x7fc7cd359ccb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0(0x7fc7cd35ac7b) [0x7fc7cd35ac7b]
./fuzzer(main+0x406) [0x5614b00d1686]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ruby

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 ruby2_keywords.rb

* Process memory map:

5614b00c9000-5614b00cd000 r--p 00000000 08:06 23653890                   /home/cyberhacker/Asioita/Hakkerointi/Fuzzing/onigmo/ext/onigmo/fuzzer
5614b00cd000-5614b00d7000 r-xp 00004000 08:06 23653890                   /home/cyberhacker/Asioita/Hakkerointi/Fuzzing/onigmo/ext/onigmo/fuzzer
5614b00d7000-5614b00da000 r--p 0000e000 08:06 23653890                   /home/cyberhacker/Asioita/Hakkerointi/Fuzzing/onigmo/ext/onigmo/fuzzer
5614b00da000-5614b00db000 r--p 00010000 08:06 23653890                   /home/cyberhacker/Asioita/Hakkerointi/Fuzzing/onigmo/ext/onigmo/fuzzer
5614b00db000-5614b00dc000 rw-p 00011000 08:06 23653890                   /home/cyberhacker/Asioita/Hakkerointi/Fuzzing/onigmo/ext/onigmo/fuzzer
5614b00dc000-5614b02dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
5614b0a08000-5614b0b40000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fc7c8737000-7fc7c8f8d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c8f8d000-7fc7c93c4000 r--s 00000000 08:06 40248810                   /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/c2/89da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e.debug
7fc7c93c4000-7fc7c95e3000 r--s 00000000 08:06 40120745                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fc7c95e3000-7fc7c9948000 r--s 00000000 08:06 40117551                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0.2
7fc7c9948000-7fc7c9977000 r--s 00000000 08:06 23653890                   /home/cyberhacker/Asioita/Hakkerointi/Fuzzing/onigmo/ext/onigmo/fuzzer
7fc7c9977000-7fc7c997a000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40108172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc7c997a000-7fc7c9991000 r-xp 00003000 08:06 40108172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc7c9991000-7fc7c9995000 r--p 0001a000 08:06 40108172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc7c9995000-7fc7c9996000 r--p 0001d000 08:06 40108172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc7c9996000-7fc7c9997000 rw-p 0001e000 08:06 40108172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc7c9997000-7fc7c9998000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9998000-7fc7c9a39000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9a39000-7fc7c9a3a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9a3a000-7fc7c9adb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9adb000-7fc7c9adc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9adc000-7fc7c9b7d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9b7d000-7fc7c9b7e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9b7e000-7fc7c9c1f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9c1f000-7fc7c9c20000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9c20000-7fc7c9cc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9cc1000-7fc7c9cc2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9cc2000-7fc7c9d63000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9d63000-7fc7c9d64000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9d64000-7fc7c9e05000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9e05000-7fc7c9e06000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9e06000-7fc7c9ea7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9ea7000-7fc7c9ea8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9ea8000-7fc7c9f49000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9f49000-7fc7c9f4a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9f4a000-7fc7c9feb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9feb000-7fc7c9fec000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7c9fec000-7fc7ca08d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca08d000-7fc7ca08e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca08e000-7fc7ca12f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca12f000-7fc7ca130000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca130000-7fc7ca1d1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca1d1000-7fc7ca1d2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca1d2000-7fc7ca273000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca273000-7fc7ca274000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca274000-7fc7ca315000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca315000-7fc7ca316000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca316000-7fc7ca3b7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca3b7000-7fc7ca3b8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca3b8000-7fc7ca459000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca459000-7fc7ca45a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca45a000-7fc7ca4fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca4fb000-7fc7ca4fc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca4fc000-7fc7ca59d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca59d000-7fc7ca59e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca59e000-7fc7ca63f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca63f000-7fc7ca640000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca640000-7fc7ca6e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca6e1000-7fc7ca6e2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca6e2000-7fc7ca783000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca783000-7fc7ca784000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca784000-7fc7ca825000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca825000-7fc7ca826000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca826000-7fc7ca8c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca8c7000-7fc7ca8c8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca8c8000-7fc7ca969000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca969000-7fc7ca96a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ca96a000-7fc7caa0b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7caa0b000-7fc7caa0c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7caa0c000-7fc7caaad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7caaad000-7fc7caaae000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7caaae000-7fc7cab4f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cab4f000-7fc7cab50000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cab50000-7fc7cabf1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cabf1000-7fc7cabf2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cabf2000-7fc7cac93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cac93000-7fc7cac94000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cac94000-7fc7cad35000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cad35000-7fc7cad36000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cad36000-7fc7ccf47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ccf47000-7fc7ccf49000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40110225                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
7fc7ccf49000-7fc7ccf5d000 r-xp 00002000 08:06 40110225                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
7fc7ccf5d000-7fc7ccf76000 r--p 00016000 08:06 40110225                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
7fc7ccf76000-7fc7ccf77000 ---p 0002f000 08:06 40110225                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
7fc7ccf77000-7fc7ccf78000 r--p 0002f000 08:06 40110225                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
7fc7ccf78000-7fc7ccf79000 rw-p 00030000 08:06 40110225                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
7fc7ccf79000-7fc7ccf81000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7ccf81000-7fc7ccf8b000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40110568                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.1
7fc7ccf8b000-7fc7ccfea000 r-xp 0000a000 08:06 40110568                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.1
7fc7ccfea000-7fc7cd001000 r--p 00069000 08:06 40110568                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.1
7fc7cd001000-7fc7cd002000 r--p 0007f000 08:06 40110568                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.1
7fc7cd002000-7fc7cd003000 rw-p 00080000 08:06 40110568                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.1
7fc7cd003000-7fc7cd005000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40110282                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7fc7cd005000-7fc7cd016000 r-xp 00002000 08:06 40110282                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7fc7cd016000-7fc7cd01c000 r--p 00013000 08:06 40110282                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7fc7cd01c000-7fc7cd01d000 ---p 00019000 08:06 40110282                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7fc7cd01d000-7fc7cd01e000 r--p 00019000 08:06 40110282                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7fc7cd01e000-7fc7cd01f000 rw-p 0001a000 08:06 40110282                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7fc7cd01f000-7fc7cd047000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40120745                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fc7cd047000-7fc7cd1dc000 r-xp 00028000 08:06 40120745                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fc7cd1dc000-7fc7cd234000 r--p 001bd000 08:06 40120745                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fc7cd234000-7fc7cd235000 ---p 00215000 08:06 40120745                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fc7cd235000-7fc7cd239000 r--p 00215000 08:06 40120745                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fc7cd239000-7fc7cd23b000 rw-p 00219000 08:06 40120745                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fc7cd23b000-7fc7cd248000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cd248000-7fc7cd256000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40120748                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
7fc7cd256000-7fc7cd2d2000 r-xp 0000e000 08:06 40120748                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
7fc7cd2d2000-7fc7cd32d000 r--p 0008a000 08:06 40120748                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
7fc7cd32d000-7fc7cd32e000 r--p 000e4000 08:06 40120748                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
7fc7cd32e000-7fc7cd32f000 rw-p 000e5000 08:06 40120748                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
7fc7cd32f000-7fc7cd358000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40117551                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0.2
7fc7cd358000-7fc7cd586000 r-xp 00029000 08:06 40117551                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0.2
7fc7cd586000-7fc7cd68c000 r--p 00257000 08:06 40117551                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0.2
7fc7cd68c000-7fc7cd693000 r--p 0035c000 08:06 40117551                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0.2
7fc7cd693000-7fc7cd694000 rw-p 00363000 08:06 40117551                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0.2
7fc7cd694000-7fc7cd6a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cd6cf000-7fc7cd6d1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc7cd6d1000-7fc7cd6d3000 r--p 00000000 08:06 40110231                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fc7cd6d3000-7fc7cd6fd000 r-xp 00002000 08:06 40110231                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fc7cd6fd000-7fc7cd708000 r--p 0002c000 08:06 40110231                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fc7cd709000-7fc7cd70b000 r--p 00037000 08:06 40110231                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fc7cd70b000-7fc7cd70d000 rw-p 00039000 08:06 40110231                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7ffca11d1000-7ffca19d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffca19e0000-7ffca19e4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffca19e4000-7ffca19e6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


Aborted (core dumped)
```

so the faulty code line is this: `VALUE module_object = rb_class_new_instance(0, NULL, rb_cOnigmo);` . `rb_cOnigmo` is a module: `VALUE rb_cOnigmo = rb_define_module("Onigmo");` and not a class, so I think that I shouldn't use `rb_class_new_instance` , but instead some other function. The problem is that I do not know what this other function is.

I basically want to accomplish this: `Onigmo.parse("a")` , but in C code.

TLDR: How to call a method of a module properly when using the ruby C api?

Comment: You're right in that you shouldn't be calling `rb_class_new_instance` on a non-class object; have you tried directly invoking your method on the module object via `rb_funcall(rb_cOnigomo, ...)`?

Comment: @mitch_ Yeah, that did the trick. I feel quite dumb that I didn't think of that before. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to mitch_ for the answer! I just had to call `rb_funcall(rb_cOnigmo, ...)` on the module object.

Comment: Yep. Even when working with Ruby's C API, everything really is an object, including the `VALUE` returned by `rb_define_module`. Therefore you can call methods on it directly.